# Add funds to PayPal from Bank Account

Tags: paypal

Is there any way to add funds to my PP account from associated bank account using PayPalAPI ?
All operations must be made without user interaction.

For example: a cron runs every month(last day) - and transfers a specific amount from bank to PayPal, so later I can make a mass pay.

Comment: maybe you should explain what you need that for. Transferring funds without user interaction sounds a bit iffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do this.

In the event of making a payment out of your PayPal account when you do not have the funds to cover it, PayPal will automatically pull those funds from your funding source (bank account) to cover the transaction.  See [ExecutePayment](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APExecutePaymentAPI).

Given the above, as far as just transferring funds from your bank to your paypal account.. I'd bet they don't see a reason to do this.  After all there's no real reason to just transfer funds to paypal, unless those funds are involved in immediately sending a payment to someone else..

Comment: Imagine following situation: I need to make 10 payments of 10$ each to 10 different PayPal emails and I have 0$ in may PayPal account.
Maybe I'm wrong, but what would happen in this case:
1. paypal extracts 100$ from bank account once and then process all payments
2. paypal extracts 100$ from bank account by making 10 operations

I think there will be 10 operations on bank account; So this is why I'm trying this way! :)

Comment: @AlexRose: Yes, there will be 10 pulls from your bank.  Does that matter?  There is no additional cost for paypal to extract it from your bank...

Comment: I tried Adaptive Payments - get the money from my bank account, but the problem is I need to confirm the transaction. Any way to avoid this? I want to send money to another account by using a cron;

Comment: @notme perhaps there is no extra cost, but how long does it take for the transfer from your bank? Not instant. This means your PayPal transaction is effectively delayed which can have an impact in some use cases, and I think this justifies the need to have a balance available on your PayPal account. Being able to do this via API would be ideal.

Comment: if i am a bank and i want my customer's account numbers to be available for usage inside paypal accounts how i can do this? also how can i provide my bank customers the ability to transfer money from the bank apps to other people's paypal accounts?

Comment: @user666: if you are a bank then call paypal and work out a deal.