# Funding business paypal account from bank via api

Tags: paypal

Yes i know this question looks similar to [Add funds to PayPal from Bank Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198003/add-funds-to-paypal-from-bank-account) , but I have a legitimate circumstance why that answer is not acceptable.

I have many recipients that I need to automatically pay out each day, and need my paypal account to have suitable funds (while only making ONE call to my bank account). My bank account has transaction limits and I therefore can't afford to make 10+ withdrawals a day.

I plan on using Mass Payments api, does anyone know if this makes one lump withdrawal for the total amount of all the payments combined that are wrapped up in a mass payment?

Alternatively, does anyone know of an api way of funding a paypal account from a bank account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way to fund your PayPal account from your bank through the API.  MassPay won't automatically do it either.  You would need to have the funds already available in PayPal for MassPay to work.